# Comparison operators on booleans trick

Tags: c++, boolean, comparison-operators, boolean-operations

In C++, the logical operators `&&`, `||`, `!` are there, which corresponds to conjunction [image], disjunction [image], negation [image], respectively.

But I noticed the comparison operators `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` can be used for booleans as well! Given that `P` and `Q` are booleans:

`P == Q` is bicontitional [image],

`P != Q` is exclusive disjunction [image],

`P < Q` is converse nonimplication [image],

`P > Q` is nonimplication [image],

`P <= Q` is implication [image],

And `P >= Q` is converse implication [image].

My questions are:

1. Will the program perform better by this trick?
2. Is there any example code using this trick (in any language)?

Comment: What's with the casts? Why not `P < Q`, `P > Q`, `P <= Q`, `P >= Q`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know <, >, <=, >= could be used to booleans as well. Thank you.

Comment: "Will the performance increase by this trick?" Increase compared to what?

Comment: The speed. Wasn't it obvious?

Comment: I mean compared to code using only `&&`, `||` and `!`?

Comment: I finished updated the assembly listings for what has been discussed. This was an interesting question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the performance increase by this trick?

On any processor where it would have any benefit, when `P` and `Q` are simple variables, this would be simple enough that you should expect compilers to make use of it already without requiring any source code rewriting.

But keep in mind that `P < Q` in general has a distinct *disadvantage* over `!P && Q`: it requires evaluation of `Q`, when the result is already known if `P` evaluates to `true`. The same applies to all the other relational operators.

> Is there any example code using this trick (in any language)?

Not as a trick, but because it arguably leads to code that's easier to understand (not any specific language):

```
if ((a == null) != (b == null))
  throw "a and b must either both be null, or both be non-null";
```

It could be written with `^`. Which is easier to read is a matter of opinion.

Comment: For the disadvantage of comparison operators over logical operators, I've posted a proposal for optimization there on ISO C++ proposal.

Comment: Good luck, but to be honest, I do not expect much to happen from it: you propose adding a special exception to the language rules which potentially changes the behaviour of existing code, and do not give any compelling use case for it. What benefit do you see in `P < Q` over `!P && Q`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think it might make the code faster. Here is the code for the first function:

```
bool biconditional(bool a, bool b)
{
    return (a && b) || (!a && !b);
}

bool biconditional_trick(bool a, bool b)
{
    return a == b;
}
```

And the generated assembly:

```
biconditional(bool, bool):
        mov     eax, esi
        xor     eax, 1
        xor     eax, edi
        ret
biconditional_trick(bool, bool):
        cmp     dil, sil
        sete    al
        ret
```

I used gcc 5.3 from [Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQZA%2BpegEwCsAbCEgB4D2uAzkSAGbYAjLQAcAB1hdKAQwBurWgApqdJiwBkXbNOwIADABokKhsySbtuwQEoyAbzJInxmqZZdBSALxItO%2FQDcjs4Q7GBaLqpmXHrevpYIgkHO8f6xPjHJzh5xNFGUHLiUXCCmih5GeabFUFAglAhiIIwALOWCRrQAzNbWWU5%2BVrmY1YXFpUzKI0wFnONlVTNjJWUVvnrWBsEpO7t7%2Bwe7i4zFuHUNTa3tRoIivVuHjwfHp%2BeNzW0xRvS9%2FUi4CGwMFwYGM0xO0jgcAuH3KCQ66z6ZAAvmQgAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g530%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%20%20-Wall%20-fno-verbose-asm%20%20-march%3Dhaswell%22%7D%5D%7D) with the flags `-O3  -Wall -fno-verbose-asm -march=haswell`.

Clearly you can shave off 1 instruction. It's interesting that gcc doesn't do this optimization. You might want to drop them an e-mail and ask why: https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html

Edit: the other answer makes a good point: logical expressions can be evaluated faster by trimming unnecessary parts. To demonstrate, I've rewritten the code to use calls to functions that return `bool` instead of `bool` arguments:

```
bool fa();
bool fb();

bool biconditional_with_function()
{
    return (fa() && fb()) || (!fa() && !fb());
}

bool biconditional_with_function_trick()
{
    return fa() == fb();
}
```

Here is the assembly:

```
biconditional_with_function():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    fa()
        test    al, al
        je      .L7
        call    fb()
        test    al, al
        jne     .L10
.L7:
        call    fa()
        mov     edx, eax
        xor     eax, eax
        test    dl, dl
        je      .L14
.L10:
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L14:
        call    fb()
        add     rsp, 8
        xor     eax, 1
        ret
biconditional_with_function_trick():
        push    rbx
        call    fa()
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    fb()
        cmp     bl, al
        pop     rbx
        sete    al
        ret
```

You can see that the code generated for `biconditional_with_function` uses jumps to skip the second half of the expression if the first half is true. Interestingly when the second half is evaluated, `fa()` and `fb()` are called overall twice since the compiler doesn't know if they always return the same result. If that is the case, the code should be rewritten by saving the evaluated results in their own variables:

```
bool biconditional_with_function_rewritten()
{
    bool a = fa();
    bool b = fb();
    return (a && b) || (!a && !b);
}
```

And the assembly:

```
biconditional_with_function_rewritten():
        push    rbx
        call    fa()
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    fb()
        xor     eax, 1
        xor     eax, ebx
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

We can see they are almost identical, just the 1 instruction difference remains, giving the "trick" method a slight advantage.

For the converse nonimplication, we can see that indeed GCC will avoid evaluating the second operator when logical operators are used, but not when the `<` operator is used:

```
bool fa();
bool fb();

bool converse_nonimplication()
{
    return !fa() && fb();
}

bool converse_nonimplication_trick()
{
    return fa() < fb();
}
```

Assembly:

```
converse_nonimplication():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    fa()
        test    al, al
        je      .L5
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L5:
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     fb()
converse_nonimplication_trick():
        push    rbx
        call    fa()
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    fb()
        cmp     al, bl
        pop     rbx
        seta    al
        ret
```

Comment: Huh, indeed. For the first example, there's an old [missed-optimization bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR42195) for GCC, though the code that gets generated now is already much better than it was back then. It's not as simple as "fewer instructions is faster", so it might be worth checking the actual instruction costs for both versions, but unless they're exactly equally fast, there's a missed optimisation in one or the other.